# How do I loop through a multiple delimited JSON file over Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm facing problem to loop over multiple delimited JSON, following is my JSON file content:

```
[{"Timestamp":"2019-05-17T18:00:00.19+08:00","Items":[{"Name":"CurrentTaskSequence","Body":{"Status":"3","Type":"MachineInfo"}}}]]
[{"Timestamp":"2019-05-17T18:00:10.502+08:00","Items":[{"Name":"CurrentTaskSequence","Body":{"Status":"1","Type":"MachineInfo"}}}]]
[{"Timestamp":"2019-05-17T18:00:05.814+08:00","Items":[{"Name":"CurrentTaskSequence","Body":{"Status":"9","Type":"MachineInfo"}}}]]
```

It doesnt work, unless I did the manually adding the commas (,) after the row work as below:

```
[{"Timestamp":"2019-05-17T18:00:00.19+08:00","Items":[{"Name":"CurrentTaskSequence","Body":{"Status":"3","Type":"MachineInfo"}}}],
{"Timestamp":"2019-05-17T18:00:10.502+08:00","Items":[{"Name":"CurrentTaskSequence","Body":{"Status":"1","Type":"MachineInfo"}}}],
{"Timestamp":"2019-05-17T18:00:05.814+08:00","Items":[{"Name":"CurrentTaskSequence","Body":{"Status":"9","Type":"MachineInfo"}}}]]
```

```py
def main():
   #Read json file
    f = open('/home/amirizzat/Desktop/data.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    #Print json
    print(data)

#call main
main()
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is quite confusing, this is my first time asking and new community here. I will elaborate more later....need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that your file isn't exactly JSON, instead it has lines and the content of each line is JSON.

You could do something like

```
with open('/home/amirizzat/Desktop/data.json') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]

print(data)
```

That loops over the lines and deserializes the JSON for each one, putting the results in an array.